# Rails: How can I put the sections together to form a book automatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, separation-of-concerns

I'm a freshman to learn Rails and working on my first project about "online book writing".

I've already made the MVC of user,book and section. Association like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections , dependent: :destroy
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
end
```

So I made a relationship between user and section,but no relationship between user and book. for example,user.1 write section.1 of book.1 ,the user.2 write section.2 of book.1.

Then I want to use all the sections of book.1 which written by different users,to form a book.1 automatically. (connect the text field directly in one text field,book_content is sum of section_content)

What should I do in the views or models?

Comment: You should have done the other way around. User has a book and the book has a section. So that you can retrieve any section of the book by doing user.book.section. Also you can do books.section to get all the sections of the book

Comment: The books appear to have sections written by different users. I think the associations are okay. I can't see what is required beyond finding a book and iterating over its sections though.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add an index field to manage the order of the sections. But for now you can do this:

```
<%= render book.sections %>
```

And then you'll need to define a partial in `sections/_section.html.(erb.haml.whatever)`